# does it make any sense save a Visual Studio Projects in SharePoint Online Portal?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, backup, save

I am trying to save a Visual Studio 2008 project to a SharePoint library as a backup. 
I dont know how. Please explain me if it does make any sense and how it is possible to import huge project with a lot of files into EMEA online Sharepoint 2007 Portal. I dont have MOSS, just WSS 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut instinct tells me this is not a good idea. It might be a better plan to save a link to where the VS 2008 back up is on Sharepoint, but adding a huge load of data to any sort of storage device is always going to be a bit fraught.

For example, whilst you can save images and files into SQL Server directly, most people prefer to save the files separately, and store the retrieval path in the database.

Comment: you mean it is better to backup vs08 project on sharepoint storage, and then just link to it? is sharepoint storage just like a harddisk on pc?

Comment: @Marek Grzenkowicz: i  want to store a VS solution in SharePoint 2007 and open it directly from there. is it bad or good idea? how can implement that?

Comment: I don't know about Sharepoint Storage, but Marek makes a very good point. If it is a Visual Studio project then surely it's a good idea to use source control to look after that.

Comment: I've not been using Sharepoint that long, so there will be others who know more, but Sharepoint uses SQL Express databases. I'd guess most things would be stored in there. So following this, Sharepoint storage isn't like the hard-disk on a pc.